# Various 'players' on a 2D Grid, how should players reference the grid?

Tags: java, oop, reference, multidimensional-array

Say I have created a class called Grid which is a 2D array and has the function

```
boolean canMove(Position fromPos, Position toPos) {
  // Determines whether a we can move from fromPos to toPos
}
```

Now say I also have a class called Player, simply choose at random one of [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT] on their turn, and call canMove() to see if they can move.

At the moment my idea is to construct each player like this:

```
public Player(String name, Grid grid) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grid = grid;
}
```

And when they try to move they can call:

```
public void move() {
  //Pick a random move
  ...

  //See if move is valid, if so make the move
  if(grid.canMove(cur_pos, new_pos) {
    move(cur_pos, new_pos);
  }
}
```

My question is, is it right to have each player referencing the grid? Since every player will always reference the same grid (there is only one), is there a way to essentially make it a given what the grid is, without having to specify it in the constructor?

Comment: Just pass in the grid when calling move?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of structuring, it doesn't really make sense for each player to have a reference to the grid. The grid class should have a 2d-array with its following player objects as instance variables.

On a side note, canMove() should not need two parameters. You only need one parameter. canMove(Position newPos) will check if that new position is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to say if we had an idea of what you're grid and movement scheme is like.

Your current setup is good if:
You are trying to drag your Player object from one tile on the grid to another.
(It's decent)

If you are trying to only move [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT], why not just make the Grid static and call a method like Grid.movePlayer(Player p, int x, int y) and handle everything in there.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is any one correct answer, but in my mind a better set up would be:

- Have a Game class that is the universe, that has access to the game logic, that controls everything. This I think is your missing piece in your set up.
- This Game class holds references to the Players, to the Grid or Grids.
- A Player who wants to move requests this of Game. Game then checks the Grid and lets Player know if the move is legal, and then makes the move. So yes, Player would have to have a reference to the Game object, but perhaps that's it. Player would not necessarily need a reference to Grid (in many but not in all situations).